# WP - Use shortcode in HTML form field

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, shortcode

I would like to use shortcodes in a HTML form on a Wordpress site.

Example:

```
  <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="[shortcode_here]" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

[Now it returns like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4XoN.png) while I would like it to [return something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0c3.png).

Anyone out there able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195665/why-do-shortcode-is-not-executing-the-shortcode-in-data-html-attributes/195673#195673

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', function ( $allowedposttags, $context ) {
    if ( $context == 'post' ) {
        $allowedposttags['input']['value'] = 1;
    }
    return $allowedposttags;
}, 10, 2 );
```